# Is there a way to show a contact's nickname in my inbox for GMail?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts

I really would like a way to show a contact's nickname in my inbox. I don't want to see email's from "John Smith", I really want to see emails from "`<nickname>`". How can I change this behavior? I can get it to work in Apple's Mail.app, but that's Apple :)